# What protocol layer does browser work on?

Tags: tcp, udp

Assume our browser is using UDP protocol; then request to the server,will it be passed through all the lower lower layers or it goes directly to the receiver end by...
If it goes all through the layers then it uses a  physical link; then how it could be a connection-less protocol? 
  Wireless uses TCP or UDP? 
please do answer me...am totally confused with this concept....

Answer (score 0):

Every application protocol specifies which transport protocol it uses.

TCP is used for the HTTP connection to the web server. UDP is normally used for performing DNS queries, although it's possible for it to switch to TCP in some cases.

Comment: Your comment in the deleted answer that 'there is no way for a web site to specify what protocol is used with it' is nonsense. The web server listens at a port, which is either TCP or UDP, and then responds via an application protocol to requests expressed in that protocol. There is no way for it *not* to specify what protocol is used with it.

Comment: But how does some random browser know that it's listening on UDP rather than TCP? In the case of listening on a nonstandard port there's a URL syntax for that (`:portnumber`), but there's no syntax to say "Use HTTP over UDP instead of TCP". Theoretically they could define a new syntax for that, e.g. `uhttp:`. However, the purpose of HTTP makes it unlikely that UDP would be a useful transport protocol.

Answer (score -1):

The browser uses HTTP, an application protocol layered over TCP, which is a connection-oriented protocol. Or else it uses HTTPS, which is HTTP over SSL over TCP.

Your remarks about UDP are both illogical and irrelevant.